# writing tf baselink -> laser

Tags: ros, lidar, frame, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I wish to do a tf baselink->laser. I am using xvlidar and it give /scan. I followed the steps here: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF
I managed to do it and it did churn out the sample output. How do I use the /scan data from the lidar and feed it to the tf?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223889/writing-tf-baselink--%3E-laser/) by [learner88](https://answers.ros.org/users/25005/learner88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your laser will output a point cloud or an array of points in a topic ("/scan" if I undestood you). This messages will have a frame_id (for example, "base_scan"). To use this points in your program you have to subscribe to this topic (see Basic Tutorials) and if you want to use your points with respect to the robot base you will have to publish the transformation from base_link to base_scan. It can be done with a [a static transform publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher).

---

Originally posted by [dfornas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25543/dfornas/) with karma: 68 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2